# Code changes in intellij have no affect while debugging. I have to clean install first and restart wildfly server

Tags: java, intellij-idea, web-applications, wildfly, remote-debugging

I am using Intellij with wildfly/jboss server and I have webapp consists of parent project and submodules. I would like to be able to see code changes in my java code in one of the submodules without having to clean install and restart. For that I have configured Remote JVM Debug as you can see in the screenshot. When I start the debugger, it stops at break points and I can debug step by step which is fine.
[image]
Problem: When I change the code like I change string variable value from a to b, this change has no affect. I have first to clean install the whole parent project and restart wildfly. Is it possible to get changes reflected without having to clean install and restart wilfly server like it is in eclipse? In eclipse I got this problem, when I forget to tick project-> automatically build but I dont know how to fix this in intellij

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: I choosen Update classes and resources but it is not working. Even restarting the server do not help, I have to clean install on parent porject